# Tab completion in Terraform console?

Tags: terraform

`terraform console` is really useful for inspecting Terraform state, but it's annoying that there is no tab completion for resource names, data sources and so on.

Should it be possible? If so, what are the steps to enable it?

(Basic bash completion for the `terraform` CLI tool is working as expected for me. It's only in `terraform console` that `TAB` does nothing useful.)

Comment: `terraform console` works fine, but can you provide details with commands to show the real problem?

Comment: `terraform console` has no tab completion at this time. The interpolation language doesn't currently have the hooks necessary to check for completions. That may come eventually, but not in the near future. :(

Answer (score 1):

Tab completion is still not available in `terraform console` (see this open [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27370)).

You may however consider using [terraform-repl](https://github.com/paololazzari/terraform-repl), an open source terraform console wrapper written in bash. Among other things, it provides tab completion for `locals`, `resources` and `data` sources.

---

Given `main.tf`:

```
locals {
  a = "foo"
  b = {"nums": [
    1
  ]}
}

data "aws_ami" "example" {
  ...
}

data "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  ...
}
```

then:

```bash
$ terraform-repl
> local.<TAB>
local.a  local.b.nums[0]
> local.b.<TAB>
> local.b.nums[0]

> data.<TAB>
data.aws_ami.example  data.aws_iam_role.example
> data.aws_a<TAB>
data.aws_ami.example

> resource.<TAB>
resource.aws_subnet.my_subnet  resource.aws_vpc.my_vpc
> resource.aws_s<TAB>
resource.aws_subnet.my_subnet
```